# Flutter application crsashes after adding google_mobile_ads

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

After adding google_mobile_ads package in my flutter app the application crashes without showing anything.
I have added the required text in the androidManifest file.
androidManifest.xml file:

```
 <application
        android:label="ad_prac"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
         
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
         
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
     
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
     
    </application>
```

main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';


void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);
  runApp(MyApp()),

}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyHomePage();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("this is $index"),
                );
              }),
        ),
      
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

i am using android emulator with google play

I have added the `Meta` tag below the `activity` tag and have tried other fixes but none are working

Comment: Can you check the `Logcat` & not the Run tab to see if there are any `RuntimeException`s?

Comment: Can you provide minimal  MyApp widget code? => runApp(MyApp())

Comment: @darshan where i can check the logcat?

Comment: @Saad, open android folder of your app from Android Studio. There should be a Logcat Tab at the bottom tabs. Also Android Studio will try to build your app, giving you more insights on what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Flutter Version latest (in Pubspec.yaml sdk version `sdk: '>=3.0.1 <4.0.0'`)
then change the gradle file in project level    `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'`

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
```

now it will work fine

Answer (score -1):

You also need to add this line to the `dependencies` section of your app-level gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0'
}
```

and make sure that the `minSdkVersion` is `19` or higher in the same file:

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 19
        ...
    }
```

[AdMob - Get started](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk)

Comment: i have added it, still not working